# How to exclude a property type from an array of classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in typescript to deeply remove a prop from a class in an array nested in another class?
this way for example:

```js
class Nested {
  propX!: string;
  propY!: string;
  propZ!: string;
}

class Parent {
  propA!: string;
  propB!: number;
  propC!: string;
  nesteds!: Nested[]; 
}

// remove propZ from nesteds in Parrant class
class ParentInput implement Exclude<Parent, 'propC'|'nesteds.propZ'> {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Do you need it recursive or you know that `nesteds` occurs only at the top level?

Comment: @A.Chiesa I don't need it recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pick` and `Exclude` to filter out properties. Since `Nested` is, well, nested, you'll have to use extra `type` declarations to get it working:

```ts
// Grab every property except for 'propZ' out of Nested.
//   This is optional: you can just use `Pick<Nested...` directly below.
type FilteredNested = Pick<Nested, Exclude<keyof Nested, 'propZ'>>

// Grab every property except for 'propC' and 'nesteds' from Parent, 
//   then intersect a new `nesteds` definition using the above type
type FilteredParent = Pick<Parent, Exclude<keyof Parent, 'propC' | 'nesteds' >> & {
    nesteds: FilteredNested[]
}

class ParentInput implements FilteredParent {
    nesteds!: FilteredNested[];
    propA!: string;
    propB!: number;
}
```

[Full Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEByCmEAu8Am0DeAoa0AOATgPZ4AaAhAFzTIECWAdgOYDcO%20xeAmlTUvcza5CJAFq9ajVlgC%20WLKEgwACmALwGSTOxF4AghP5ShHEgCFeDAK4BbAEbwCJ3QGFDA6bgaIUqCLwRkNABtAF0WaFl5JABPPHhoADE6EBR1VEDfaABeaGU6YABrAB5MtAAaaABRAA9QK1R4YsL4GKIAMzgfCugAcl1RXoA%20IaxY%20KSUtLRVdU0cvIKS2Y0kStr6xubWjry1Vcr%20zhde6AAfPu8gv1OR6AAybQBIK98IamTUxzQy1DCohTgKB7OZIACSDDwVi0dBseBA8Bsqxgn2mqBW82wL26fl4qO%20GRxYTYT10BmokkEWFJnAs1Gs9kcbBkQA)